# MSSQL Cursor Return all rows into a single column

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to return a list of all image names as a single result from an MSSQL CURSOR with the following stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPhotosByPropId]
    @propId bigint
AS
    DECLARE @AllPhotos nvarchar(MAX) 
    DECLARE @PhotoName nvarchar(500) 
    DECLARE @BaseURL nvarchar(200) 
    DECLARE @PhotosCursor CURSOR
    DECLARE @PhotosCount int


    -- Take Photo Count
    SET @PhotosCount = (SELECT Count(*) FROM [ART].[dbo].[STR_FK_PropertyPhoto] Where PropId = @propId)

    -- Take all photos in Cursor
    SET @PhotosCursor = CURSOR FAST_Forward For
     SELECT [Photo_File_Name],[Base_URL]
       FROM [ART].[dbo].[STR_FK_PropertyPhoto]
      WHERE PropId = @propId

    -- OPEN CURSOR for first record
    OPEN @PhotosCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @PhotosCursor 
    INTO @PhotoName, @BaseURL             

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        SET @AllPhotos =  @AllPhotos + ',' +  @PhotoName                  
        FETCH NEXT FROM @PhotosCursor 
        INTO @PhotoName, @BaseURL
    END

    select @AllPhotos as "Img"

    CLOSE  @PhotosCursor 
    DEALLOCATE  @PhotosCursor 
    Go
```

The expected result is something like `'1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg'` is returned, but instead the outcome is `NULL`.

Comment: what version of SQL Server?  You don't need a `CURSOR` to concatenate rows into a single line -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways of doing this without using a cursor. But, if you insist on keeping your existing code, then initiate @AllPhotos first. Right now, it is `NULL` and whatever you add still equates to `NULL`

```
DECLARE @AllPhotos nvarchar(MAX) = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

In the string concatenation `SET @AllPhotos =  @AllPhotos + ',' +  @PhotoName`, if any one of the Photo_File_Name entries from the cursor is `NULL` the end result will be `NULL`.

Changing your cursor query to the following will ensure that NULL values are returned as an empty string.

```
-- Take all photos in Cursor
SET @PhotosCursor = CURSOR FAST_Forward For
 SELECT COALESCE([Photo_File_Name], '') AS Photo_File_Name,
        [Base_URL]
   FROM [ART].[dbo].[STR_FK_PropertyPhoto]
  WHERE PropId = @propId
```

Note however that this will now return something like `'1.jpg,2.jpg,,4.jpg'` if, for example, the third `Photo_File_Name` was `NULL`.

This is easily remedied by wrapping the `SET` in an `IF` clause:

```
IF (@PhotoName <> '')
BEGIN
    SET @AllPhotos = @AllPhotos + ',' + @PhotoName
END
```